Is it correct to say "I am rolling my friend singing" in everyday English?
I am pointing my smartphone (which has a camera) at my friend who is singing. I want to create video of him singing.
I heard people say "roll" in films (couldn't remember the films). But in the film, they just say "I am rolling".
If I want to say a complete sentence, can I say "I am rolling my friend singing" but can I say "rolling" when I am just holding my smartphone? I am not rolling my thing like a professional camera.
There are other phrases I can think of
"I am filming my friend singing" but this is just a family video. "Filming" is more for a director who is making a film.
or "I am recording my friend singing"
or "I am taking a video of my friend singing"

Are you trying to sound like a professional director or cameraperson, or do you want to know what words ordinary English speakers would commonly use?

@StuartF, I am looking for a phrase used in everyday English

No. It doesn't make sense.    Try: filming, videoing, recording.  All are useable here.

When capturing a video of your friend singing with your smartphone, the most natural and commonly used phrases would be:

"I am recording my friend singing." - This is a simple and clear way to describe what you're doing.

"I am taking a video of my friend singing."


Using "I am filming my friend singing" is also acceptable, although it can sometimes carry the connotation of something more formal or professional. However, it's increasingly common to hear "filming" used casually, even when using a smartphone, and is certainly not a mark of a non-native speaker.
As for "I am rolling my friend singing," this would not be a correct usage. The term "rolling" is almost exclusively used in professional film and video production contexts and is typically paired with "camera," as in "camera rolling." It’s not usually followed by a direct object pronoun, and you wouldn’t say that you’re "rolling" something, unless it were related to cinematography, such as rolling the sound.
For example you might hear or read phrases like:

"We're rolling, so everyone quiet on set!"
"Camera rolling, and action!"
"As soon as the director called for silence on set, the crew ensured everything was in place, and with a nod from the camera operator, the cameras started rolling.

If you're using your smartphone, you'd say, "I'm recording my friend singing" or "I'm taking a video of my friend singing," rather than "I'm rolling my friend singing."

SOUND? - Set. CAMERA? - Set. ROLL SOUND. - Sound rolling. ROLL CAMERA. - Camera speed. MARKER. - Scene 1, Roll 1, Take 1 etc.

Yeah, "rolling" in this sense is intransitive.

Until you explained the situation, the elliptical "I am rolling my friend singing" in the question title made little sense to me.
When an old-school film camera was capturing footage, we could say that the camera was rolling.  A war-journalist who wanted to document a particular situation might instruct the cameraman in the crew to "Roll the camera! Roll the f_____ camera!".
But the verb isn't normally used transitively with the thing or action being filmed in direct object position:

I'm rolling the monk confronting the platoon. unidiomatic
Roll the monk confronting the platoon. unidiomatic

The verb get could be used there:

Get the monk confronting the platoon.
I'm getting my friend singing.

recording is also idiomatic there,  everyone would understand it, and it is in a neutral register, whereas getting is colloquial.

What the OP heard

I am rolling.

is likely an elided form of

I am rolling [the camera].

M+W sense 4b defines roll and gives an example similar to the one here:

to cause to begin operating or moving


roll the cameras

The OP’s suggestion

I am rolling my friend singing

wouldn't work, but this should be fine:
I am rolling my camera to record my friend singing.
This should be fine even for a camera not of the professional filming type.
The OP’s other three suggestions with filming, recording, and taking a video sound fine.
